# Is there a certification process or agency for ERC-20 tokens?

Tags: erc-20

The [EMV site](https://emovieventure.com/emovieventure-4-dummies/) claims that their token contracts are officialy ERC-20 certified and is listed here (then they give their EtherScan address).

My question is whether there is a certification agency or process. 
I realize ERC-20 is a standard that can be followed, but is there some way to certify or validate that it actually followed?

Comment: ERC-20 is more programming framework or interface than something strictly keeping rules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**: There is no such ERC-20 certification!!

 they might mean that there token is listed and recognized as an ERC20 compliant token on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/token-search). As i know ERC20 is still a [draft proposal](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/610) without full consensus so how can an entity certify for such thing??

Answer (score 2):

There is no official certification process for ERC-20 tokens. However [OpenZeppelin team](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity) (creators of the standard) do the audits of the ERC-20 based projects on their [official blog [audits]](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/tagged/audit) where everybody can read them for free.