# Are there any code quality certifications or standards for smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, bug

In light of recent statistics on # of bugs in smart contracts and the DAO heists I like to know if there are any kind of smart contract quality certification framework , smart contract standards or even smart contract best practices in the context of Ethereum?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant when you said "certification framework", but this might partially answer your question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/is-there-a-certification-process-or-agency-for-erc-20-tokens

Answer (score 0):

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security-considerations.html

...if you're using solidity...

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugs.html

for known bugs

Comment: Also, http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/style-guide.html for the style guide for code structure and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [OpenZeppelin](https://openzeppelin.org/). To quote their site:

> OpenZeppelin is an open framework of reusable and secure smart contracts in the Solidity language.

They have a lot of smart contract best practices, sample code, and have even done [security audits](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/tagged/audit) for a variety of projects in the space.